# Cannot install spatie/laravel-permission

Tags: laravel

I need help upon installing spatie laravel permission.

```
PS D:\xampp\team zeus\CecilianPortal> composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^5.11 for spatie/laravel-permission
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update spatie/laravel-permission
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v10.25.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/framework v10.25.2 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.    
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v10.25.2 requires composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.    
    - spatie/laravel-ignition 2.3.0 requires illuminate/support ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.25.2].
    - spatie/laravel-ignition is locked to version 2.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

Comment: In other words, update `composer-runtime` to the version required

Comment: Yes, update composer-runtime, like @dbf said. Or easier: delete composer.lock and run composer install